# Jetpack compose Drag gesture updating state

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

in my below code, i can see on swiping right my `onNextPress` only gets called once and also in logs currIndex is always 0. Why is that ?

basically i want the user to swipe right for next image and left for prev image.

```
@Composable
fun RenderGreeting() {

    var (currIndex, setCurrIndex) = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }


    var currData: MyItem = myMutableObjectList[currIndex]


    fun onNextPress() {
        if (currIndex < myMutableObjectList.size - 1) {
            Log.d("Gaurav drag press cuteee","press ${currIndex}")
            setCurrIndex(currIndex + 1)

        }
    }

    fun onPrevPress() {
        Log.d("Gaurav drag press","press")
        if (currIndex > 0) {
            Log.d("Gaurav drag press nowww","press")
            setCurrIndex(currIndex - 1)
        }
    }



    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().pointerInput(Unit) {
            var totalDrag = 0f
            detectHorizontalDragGestures(onHorizontalDrag = {change, dragAmount -> totalDrag+= dragAmount},
                onDragStart = {}, onDragEnd = {
                    if(totalDrag > 0) {
                        onNextPress()
                    } else {
                        onPrevPress()
                    }
//                    totalDrag = 0f
                    Log.d("Gaurav drag", "onDragEnd: $totalDrag")

                }, onDragCancel = {})
        }
    ) {
        RenderThings(currData)
        RenderButtons(currIndex, {
            onNextPress()
        }, { onPrevPress() })
    }

}
```

basically i want the user to swipe right for next image and left for prev image.

Comment: A hint, Jetpack Compose includes a predefined `Pager` Composable in recent versions. In case you were not aware of that: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/pager/package-summary

Comment: @BenjyTec thanks for it. wasnt aware. but functionalityy wise why is my code not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few points.

```
(currIndex, setCurrIndex) = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
```

to

```
var currIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
```

You can set it this way.

```
fun onNextPress() {
    if (currIndex < myMutableObjectList.size - 1) {
        currIndex += 1

    }
}

fun onPrevPress() {
    if (currIndex > 0) {
       currIndex -= 1
    }
}
```

You should reset totalDrag.

```
onDragStart = {
    totalDrag = 0f
}
```

You misinterpreted the logic of the swipe gesture :)

```
if(totalDrag > 0) {
   onNextPress()
   } else {
   onPrevPress()
 }
```

to

```
if(totalDrag > 0) {
    onPrevPress()
   } else {
    onNextPress()
 }
```

Comment: I think the first point you are mentioning is actually not a problem, as the `(val, setVal) = remember { ... }` notation is supported by Jetpack Compose. See https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables

Comment: yes, you are right, the documentation says so. But this does not explain why the index did not change in the previous code.

Comment: @FarukKaraca thats great.  `var currIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }`  actually worked. still not sure why it didnt work with.

Comment: In your example, `RenderGreeting()` is recomposed every time the `setCurrIndex()` function is executed. In the solution, `RenderGreeting()` is not fully recomposed. When debugging, you'll observe this difference. While `remember` assures that the variable won't be reset, this behavior makes me question if it actually is not being reset. I'm uncertain whether this is a bug or intended behavior.